# git clone to EC2 from corporate gitlab

Tags: git, networking, amazon-ec2

I have set up EC2 in private subnet and Bastion host in public subnet. I am able to ssh from my computer to the private subnet through Bastion, by adding inbound rules on port 22. Now I want to to git clone a repo from corporate gitlab from our internal network to the private EC2.
My inbound rule on the private EC2 is simple - source - IPv4 CIDR of the public subnet with Bastion host on port 22. Then on Bastion I have 2 inbound rules on port 22, with sources- my IP address for SSH access into Bastion, and the other one is IP address of our gitlab server. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. I am not very experienced with these issues and I would appreciate any help or tips. Cheers.

edit: for clarification, I have NAT gateway and IGW all set up and I am able to clone a public repo from github e.g., just cant clone a repo from internal gitlab.